# How to query google app engine database

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have imported a mysql database into my google app engine. But I can't query it. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

The https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/dev-access contains links to examples for all the languages supported by App Engine:

- Java: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide
- Python: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/developers-guide
- PHP: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/
- Go: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/cloud-sql/